# AttributeError: 'StartQT4' object has no attribute 'accept'

Tags: python, qt

I'm trying to program a quick dialog with QT4 and Python.
I've generated the Python class, using pyuic4, and tried to make a small python script to start it up:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from ConfigGUI import Ui_ConfigGUI

class StartQT4(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_ConfigGUI()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = StartQT4()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When I try to run it, it says `AttributeError: 'StartQT4' object has no attribute 'accept'`.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: This probably comes from the `ConfigGUI`, so without the `ui` file, it will be hard to help, but I would guess that you based your design on a QDialog, but here you try to integrate it into a QMainWindow. The ui tries to bind the `accept` slot which is only available in a QDialog. Please include the ConfigGUI for a better help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I managed to reproduce your problem. You selected a form based on dialogs in the QtDesigner, but are trying to construct it inside a `QMainWindow`.

[image: Form base selection dialog in QtDesigner]

The UI code tries to bind its buttons to default dialog slots `accept`and `reject` which are not available in a `QMainWindow`.

*From ConfigGUI.py:*

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.buttonBox, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("accepted()")), Dialog.accept)
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.buttonBox, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("rejected()")), Dialog.reject)
```

> The class contains a method called `setupUi()`. This takes a single argument which is the widget in which the user interface is created. The type of this argument (typically `QDialog`, `QWidget` or `QMainWindow`) is set in Designer. We refer to this type as the *Qt base class*.
>
> -- http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/designer.html

So, either select *Main Window* in the Designer as a *base class*, or change the inheritance of `StartQT4` to `QtGui.QDialog`.

Comment: Is there any good way to switch it from a Dialog to a Main Window, or should I simply change the inheritance?

Comment: It seems you can do both, so choose the one you want. Actually, it seems you are just following a tutorial, but that your application is based on a Main Window or a Dialog makes a difference, in a real application you wouldn't have the choice. Any way, to switch to a main window, open you project in Designer and select File>New an create a new Main Window. It will appear alongside your Dialog and you can then move your widgets to the main window and delete the empty dialog.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I was just making a quick GUI to edit a config file with, so I've realized the application being a Dialog isn't actually a problem for me.