# Atribute Error PyQt4 no attribute 'setFrameShape'

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, attributeerror

Hello I have a problem with PyQt4.

I created an simple Project in the Qt Designer, but I can't run it.
I tried some codes an changed a lot, but I get the same Error every time:
AttributeError: 'MyApp' object has no attribute 'setFrameShape'

So thats my code to run the .py code, with I converted from the .ui:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from qt_test import Ui_Frame


class Example(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Frame()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = Example()
    form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


main()
```

And here is the Code from qt_test.py with I converted from the .ui file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'qt_test.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Frame(object):
    def setupUi(self, Frame):
        Frame.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Frame"))
        Frame.resize(493, 451)
        Frame.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        Frame.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Raised)
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(Frame)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout"))
        self.listWidget = QtGui.QListWidget(Frame)
        self.listWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("listWidget"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.listWidget)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Frame)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)

        self.retranslateUi(Frame)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Frame)

    def retranslateUi(self, Frame):
        Frame.setWindowTitle(_translate("Frame", "Frame", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Frame", "PushButton", None))
```

So thanks if some one could help me,
Justus

Comment: show the content of `qt_test`

Comment: See my answer. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on other answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29303901/attributeerror-startqt4-object-has-no-attribute-accept), I'd say you're trying to push a QFrame design into a QMainWindow. Also, "Example" class inherite from QMainWindow but the QWidget constructor is the one called, which is weird.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to create a design using the Qt Designer tool, use the following when in dialog.

[image]

In this dialog you can choose elements of 2 blocks:

- Templates/Forms
- Widgets

In both cases what it provides is a design is not widget so in the end if we want to use it, this will be possible through a widget, but the widget depends on the initial choice for it we must have the following considerations:

1. If I choose some Template / Forms then you must choose the widget according to the following table.

---

```
+-----------------------------+--------------+
| Template                    | Widget Class |
+-----------------------------+--------------+
| Dialog with Buttons Bottom  | QDialog      |  
| Dialog with Buttons Right   | QDialog      |
| Dialog without Buttons      | QDialog      |
| MainWindow                  | QMainWindow  |
| Widget                      | QWidget      | 
+-----------------------------+--------------+
```

---

2. Instead if you choose the designs of the second block you must use the widget that names there.

In your case I think you have chosen `QFrame` as a design so you should use that widget as shown below:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from qt_test import Ui_Frame


class Example(QtGui.QFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QFrame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Frame()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = Example()
    form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

main()
```

*Note:*

- If you are going to inherit from some class you must call the constructor of that class, for example in your initial code you are inheriting from `QMainWindow` but you are calling the `QWidget` constructor. The problem can be generated because the constructor performs certain basic tasks to configure so if you do not call it you can get unexpected behavior.
- To get the behavior that you configure through Qt Designer this calls certain methods when you convert it to .py, for example in your case:

`Frame.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
 Frame.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Raised)`

So if you use another widget, it will not have these methods and generates the error you have obtained.